# Embed Mono in a C++ application, using mono internal calls with HandleRef

Tags: c#, c++, mono

I have an embed Mono runtime in a C++ application, and the bindings are written using Mono internal calls `mono_add_internal_call`, I recently found that a managed object can get [collected while calling one of the c++ functions](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/#gc-safe-pinvoke-code), and that can be a problem since the finalizer calls another function to delete the pointer instance (that is kept in the class as an IntRef).

I have read that I should use a HandleRef or SafeHandle, and I'm going to go with HandleRef.

My question is, since internal calls do not have automatic marshalling, can I just change IntPtr to HandleRef in the extern function and keep the C/C++ function as is, or do I have to do something else?

Something like this:

```
//C#
class SomeClass {
private HandleRef ptr;// previously was private IntPtr ptr;
...
}

[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
public extern static void doSomething(HandleRef ptr);//previously was ...(IntPtr ptr);

//C++
void doSomething(MyClass* obj)
```

Comment: Yes.  Or add `GC.KeepAlive(this)` after the doSomething call.

Comment: @Hans Passant Thanks, `GC.KeepAlive(this)` seems like a good option, I will use it since it probably is the most lightwheight. Regarding `HandleRef`, I tested it before asking this question, and it did work, but I couldn't find anything in the documetation that explicitly says that the IntPtr is the first element of the struct (so that it works without marshalling), all I could find was [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.handleref(v=vs.110).aspx), but it doesn't say its `LayoutKind`. Do you have any reference that states this?

Comment: @Hans Passant - Or if it works once it means it's secure to always use it as long as the struct is not changed (and it will not, supposing I will only use Mono that is)? (.NET might have a different implementation, right?)  I'm new to Mono and .NET and have no idea how this works. Thanks again.